# Is it possible to get $_COOKIE with TypoScript?

Tags: cookies, typo3, typoscript

In TypoScript exists the possibility to get the environment variable [HTTP_COOKIE_VARS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) (which is deprecated):

```
10 = TEXT
10.data = global : HTTP_COOKIE_VARS | some_cookie
```

I got this [from the documentation](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.6.0/view/1/2/).

But on my server (PHP 5.3) this variable is empty! I suppose this is because this environment variable is deprecated. Now I am running out of options, without using an extension, user function or user condition.

Maybe you have an idea! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this should do the job (at least with TYPO3 4.5 and PHP 5.3.8):

```
10 = TEXT
10.data = global:_COOKIE|some_cookie
10.wrap = <h2>Cookie: |</h2>
```

Comment: works with latest version of TYPO3 as well, tested in 10.4.15

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in functionality for the `$_COOKIE` variable.

You can however write a hook which implements the `tslib_content_getDataHook` interface and register it via

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_content.php']['getData'][] = 'path/to/your/class.user_cookiehook.php';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[request.getCookieParams()['some_cookie'] == 'some_value']
Your Code
[end]
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.